# SQL Select based on each row of previous select

Tags: select, sql-server-2012

I have a table with answers regarding different questions, all of them numbered. There are basically these columns: `IdAnswer` (unique for each answer in the table), `IdUser` (which won't repeat even if the same user answer questions a second time), `IdQuestion` and `Answer`.

```
IdAnswer    IdUser    IdQuestion    Answer
   1         John         1           0
   2         John         4           1
   3         John         5           1
   4         John         6           0
   5         Bob          1           1
   6         Bob          3           1
   7         Bob          5           0
   8         Mark         2           0
   9         Mark         7           1
   10        Mark         5           0
```

I'd like to select from this table all answers to a specific question (say, `IdQuestion` = 5), and also the last question each user answered just before question number 5.

In the end I need a table that should look like this:

```
IdAnswer    IdUser    IdQuestion    Answer
   2         John         4           1
   3         John         5           1
   6         Bob          3           1
   7         Bob          5           0
   9         Mark         7           1
   10        Mark         5           0
```

I've managed to make this work using a cursor to iterate through each line from the first `SELECT` result (which filters by `IdQuestion`), but I'm not sure if this is the best (and fastest) way of doing it. Is there any more efficient way of achieving the same result?

And by the way, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Comment: What SQL version? Add the version-specific tag to your question as the solution may vary accordingly.

Comment: Ok, just did that, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `LEAD` function

```
select * from 
(
select *,NextQ = Lead(IdQuestion)over(partition by IdUser order by IdAnswer)
from youtable
) a
Where 5 in (IdQuestion, NextQ )
```

for older versions

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT prev_id = Min(CASE WHEN IdQuestion = 5 THEN rn - 1 END) OVER( partition BY IdUser),*
         FROM   (SELECT rn = Row_number()OVER(partition BY IdUser ORDER BY IdAnswer),*
                 FROM   Yourtable)a)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn IN ( prev_id, prev_id + 1 )
```

Comment: I tried it and this actually took a little longer than the cursor method, but on the other hand it is a lot easier to use. I'll take a look at these LEAD and PARTITION functions.